# Problem with FFMPEG and PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I know this isn't exactly a programming question per se, but rather a settings question, but still:

I'm trying to convert video with FFMPEG with a PHP script, following this tutorial:

> http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/05/20/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/

FFMPEG works perfectly and I've used it from the command line a number of times. PHP also seems to work fine. I've also installed ffmpeg-php and it seems to be loading file.

The problem lies when I try to do the following in PHP:

> $srcFile = "p1.avi";
>
> $ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($srcFile);

No matter what, PHP will return this:

> Warning: can't open movie file p1.avi in /var/www/converter.php on line xx

Obviously, whatever call I do afterwards with $ffmpegObj will throw a fatal error. I'm absolutely stuck and extensive googling hasn't helped much.

If you must know, I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 with the default LAMP server packages as well as php5-ffmpeg, and I've compiled ffmpeg following a tutorial I found on Ubuntuforums (I'd link to it but stackoverflow won't let me)

Thanks!

Comment: does `file_exists($srcFile)` return true?

Comment: Whoa, actually it does return false. How can I solve this?

Thank you for giving me a clue :)

Comment: Wait, false alarm: file_exists does return true (after many tests, the file wasn't where it was supposed to be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the user you run the script as have permission to open the file?  Check with `ls -l /var/www/flashvideo/p1.avi`

Answer (score 1):

FINALLY! As some of you suggested, neither the directory nor the file had the proper permissions to be modified by my script. I changed them and everything works now =) . I'm such an idiot for not noticing this for hours :P

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify full path to you movie like following:

```
$srcFile = "/home/path/something/p1.avi";
$ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($srcFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already tried as many combinations as I could before asking here.

My web server root directory is /var/www .
My script is /var/www/converter.php .
My video is on /var/www/flashvideo/p1.avi .
I've tried the following paths:
flashvideo/p1.avi
/var/www/flashvideo/p1.avi

I've also tried moving p1.avi to /var/www and trying with p1.avi and /var/www/p1.avi with no luck ;_;

Comment: Try to move it to `/tmp/1.avi` and set 666 permisions: `chmod 666 /tmp/1.avi`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but since I just ran into this... If ffmpeg_movie is passed a corrupt movie, it seems it'll also throw a warning. There's no way to tell until you actually try to create the object. Best solution I had was to suppress the warning, and then check for the resource before interacting with it:

```
$movie = @new ffmpeg_movie($path_to_file,false);
$duration = isset($movie->ffmpeg_movie)?intval($movie->getDuration()):'Bad File?';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It's neither wrong path nor a corrupt movie related. Path is absolute, file exists and readable and permissions are 0777. Sadly, I have no idea what to do with this.

UPD: The problem was an outdated (from repos) ffmpeg version with a lot of bugs.